# Not matching string where hyphen(-) comes using regulaer expression

Tags: php, regex

I  have regular expression like below.

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/\{\%\s*block_(\w*)\s*\%\}/', function ($block){ 
        $block_file = $block[1].'.block';
}
```

when `{% block_contact_us %}`  comes it find the match... but when `{% block_contact-us %}`  comes  it fail..

Comment: `(\w+)` => `([\w-]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-` in a character class:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/\{\%\s*block_([\w-]*)\s*\%\}/', function ($block){ 
//                                        here __^^^^^
        $block_file = $block[1].'.block';
}
```

`[\w-]` matches alphanumeric, underscore and dash.

Comment: Yes, this is a quick and lazy answer - but do they actually want to match `{block_---------------}`?

Comment: @georg: I don't know. Only OP can answer.